# How to use download in Kendo grid detail template

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-core

Using Kendo Ui in Asp.net core application.

We are using a kendoGrid with a detail template. For example, the main grid displays orders, the detail template shows order details. This is working as expected.

The problem we have is that the [Export to Excel] button is not working. When clicked, nothing happens, no errors. I expect that the order rows would download.

How can I use the [Export to Excel] feature when a Detail Template is being used?

Is there another way to download the kendoGrid data in this scenario?

This partial example displays a kendoGrid with a detail template. The "excel" toolbar is added with the "excel:{}" option. Clicking this button does nothing.

Is there a way to make this work?

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        var element = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
          toolbar: ["excel"],
        excel: {
            fileName: "Kendo UI Grid Export.xlsx",
        },
            dataSource: {
                type: "odata",
                transport: {
                    read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Employees"
                },
                pageSize: 20,
                serverPaging: true,
                serverSorting: true
            },
            height: 550,
            sortable: true,
            pageable: false,
            detailTemplate: kendo.template($("#template").html()),
            detailInit: detailInit,
```

Comment: Are you sure there is no error in the console? jszip.min.js is required for that button to work. Do you have it loaded on the page?

Comment: You are correct. I added jszip.min.js to the page and now my download method works:         var grid = $('#my-grid').data("kendoGrid");  grid.saveAsExcel();